# Kendo Grid Change dynamic columns title on databound

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo Grid with no columns definition because grid's fields are dynamics and I don't have any chance to know the fields before databound event.
Example:

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: appPath + "Controller/GetGridData",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                dataSourceID: dataSourceId
            }
        },
    },
    schema: { data: "data", total: "total"},   
    pageSize: 10,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
});

 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        filterable: {
            extra: false
        },
        dataBound: function (data) {

        },
        pageable: {
            pageSizes: true,
            pageSizes: [10, 20, 50, 100]
        }
)}
```

Is there a way to modify columns headers dynamically on databound event or after data are loaded but before showing it to users?

Comment: How far you would go for this? I mean, I think it isn't possible with built-in ways, but you can dealing with the request outside the grid, which is not so good. I say that because the only way to change any option(that includes the columns definitions) is with `setOptions` and you can't call it inside any event, because that method recreates the entire widget.

Comment: I have to change columns title to implement headers translations in javascript. I think a possible way is to put my code after grid is built. I don't know if there's a way to know when the grid is built and bounded.

Comment: The problem is: if you call `setOptions` after the creation, it will recreate and then open a new request to the server again.. The way I think maybe possible, is to request with `$.ajax` outside the grid.

Comment: Because I'm using ServerPaging and filtering It is not possible..

Comment: Well, one thing you can do is to manipulate widget's DOM directly: http://dojo.telerik.com/Ajivi But keep in mind that in case of a widget refresh that modification could be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved "dynamic" column headers (after many infuriating troubleshooting messages back and forth by Telerik) by requesting the data prior to initialising the `grid` via an `AJAX` call then determining the column names based on the data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/GetGridData",
        // *Important* stringify the server-bound object
        data: JSON.stringify(dataSourceId),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: true,
        success: function(response) {
            // response contains data required for grid datasource
            ConstructGrid(response);
        }
    });

function ConstructGrid(gridData) {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
       ... attributes
       data: gridData,
       ... more attributes
    });
    var columnsArray = [];
    if(gridData.attributeToCheck = "someValue") {
       columnsArray.push({field: attributeEqualToSomeValue, title="attributeMatchingSomeValue"});
    }
    else {
        columnsArray.push({field: attributeNotEqualToSomeValue, title="attributeNotMatchingSomeValue"});
    }
    .. continue to add more columns based on data then initialise grid
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        filterable: {
            extra: false
        },
        columns: columnsArray,
        pageable: {
            pageSizes: true,
            pageSizes: [10, 20, 50, 100]
        }
    )};
}
```

Not exactly 100% dynamic but it will change the column names based on the values retrieved from the AJAX call and AFAIK (after chatting back and forth with Telerik), truly dynamic columns are not supported by the grid control.

Comment: Thank you,  good solution. For my problem I think it's better to translate DataTable columns name on Server side.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Jsbin

```
`https://output.jsbin.com/lesoxes/`
```

In this example i have used kendo's datasource.

you will get all column details in console.

Might Help You

Comment: OP wants to "change dynamic column titles" though.. Do you know if there a method available to do this once you have access to the column array?